# Utilizar TComponent con una interface en Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hola soy nueva en Delphi, he visto que este no tiene un recolector de basura como java, a excepción de implementar una interfaz, las he probado y he notado que si se libera la memoria de manera automatica pero quise llegar un punto más allá al utilizarlas en conjunto con TComponent y me lleve la gran sorpresa de que no me libera la memoria, ¿saben de alguna manera de lograr que la memoria si se libere de manera automática implementando TComponente y una interfaz en una clase? mi código es el siguiente:

```
    IGestor = Interface
        ['{F057668C-2228-4DE2-A974-314788CE26EC}']
          procedure Conectar(nombreUsuario:string;contrasena:string;puerto: integer);
        end;
    
      
       TMasterDBMS = class (TComponent)
        
          function Activar(gestor:string; num1: integer):String; virtual;
    
       end;
    
       TOracle = class(TMasterDBMS, IGestor)
          procedure Conectar(nombreUsuario:string;contrasena:string;puerto: integer); 
          function Activar(gestor:string; num1: integer):String; override;
          constructor create();
    
       end;
    
       TSQLServer = class(TInterfacedObject, IGestor)
         procedure Conectar(nombreUsuario:string;contrasena:string;puerto: integer);
        constructor create();
       end;
    
       TConection = class
         DBMS:IGestor;
         constructor create();
         function AsignarGestor(num:integer):string;
         procedure ConectarDBMS(DBMS1:IGestor);
       end;
    
       // Componentes del Form
       TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Label1: TLabel;
        Label2: TLabel;
        Button1: TButton;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    
    
       private
         { private declarations }
       public
         { public declarations }
       end;
    
     var
       Form1: TForm1;
       Conectar: TConection;
       Master: TMasterDBMS;
       Ora: TOracle;
       ciclo: integer;
    
    
     implementation
    
     {$R *.dfm}
    
    
     function TMasterDBMS.Activar(gestor:string; num1: integer):String;
     begin
        Result:='Activar Master (padre)';
        showmessage(Result);
     end;
    
     constructor TConection.Create();
     begin
      showmessage('Se creo Conection');
     end;
    
     function TConection.AsignarGestor(num:integer):string;
     begin
    
       if num=1 then begin
          Self.DBMS := TOracle.create();
          Self.ConectarDBMS(Self.DBMS);
          result := 'oracle';
          Form1.Label1.Caption := result;
    
       end else begin
          Self.DBMS := TSQLServer.create();
          Self.ConectarDBMS(Self.DBMS);
          result := 'sql server';
          Form1.Label1.Caption:=result;
       end;
     end;
    
     procedure TConection.ConectarDBMS(DBMS1: IGestor);
     begin
           DBMS1.Conectar('Nombre_BD','1234',1433);
     end;
    
    constructor TOracle.Create();
     begin
      showmessage('Se creo Oracle');
     end;
    
     procedure TOracle.Conectar(nombreUsuario:string;contrasena:string;puerto: integer);
     begin
        ShowMessage('Conexion Oracle Usuario:'+nombreUsuario+' Contraseña:'+contrasena);  
     end;
    
    
     function TOracle.Activar(gestor:string; num1: integer):String;
     begin
        inherited Activar(gestor,num1);
    
        Result:='Activar Oracle (hijo)';
        showmessage(Result);
     end;
    
    
     constructor TSQLServer.Create();
     begin
        showmessage('Se creo SQLServer');
     end;
    
     procedure TSQLServer.Conectar(nombreUsuario:string;contrasena:string;puerto: integer);
     begin
        ShowMessage('Conexion SQL Server, Usuario:'+nombreUsuario+' Contraseña:'+contrasena);  
     end;
    
    
     procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    
     begin
          Conectar := nil;
    
          ciclo:=1;
          while ciclo <=100000 do
           begin
              try
                Conectar := TConection.Create();
                Conectar.AsignarGestor(StrToInt(Edit1.Text));
              finally
                FreeAndNil(Conectar);
              end;
    
              inc(ciclo);
           end;
           ShowMessage(IntToStr(ciclo));
           Label1.Caption:='';
    
     end;

     procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Ora:=nil;
  try
     Ora := TOracle.Create();
     Ora.Activar('Oracle',1);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Ora);
  end;
end;

    
    
    end.
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Si es posible realizar la liberación automática de un componente que implementa una interfaz, pero debes saber lo que estás haciendo, pues los componentes ya tienen su método de liberación _automática_ a través de su _owner_. Antes de escribir una respuesta, debo preguntar ¿por qué razón estás derivando esta conexión de un componente y no de `TInterfacedObject`?

Comment: Lo realizo de esta manera para realizar una prueba, porque quiero ver si es posible cambiar todo el codigo de un proyecto a utilizarlo con esto y así que ya no sea necesario el uso de FreeAndNil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es posible hacer que un componente, que a su vez implementa interfaces, se libere automáticamente utilizando un contador automático de referencias o [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) (tal como lo hace la clase `TInterfacedObject`).

Para ello, vamos a revisar un poco primero los dos modelos de administración de memoria que podrían entrar en conflicto aquí:

## `TComponent` y su modelo de propiedad

`TComponent` es una clase que permite establecer una relación de propiedad entre diferentes instancias (componentes), lo que permite *delegar* a este propietario la liberación de los componentes que son de su propiedad.

Por ello, cuándo se crea un componente, se indica como parámetro del constructor quién es su propietario. Cada componente mantiene una lista de los componentes que son de su propiedad y, cuándo se va a liberar, los libera también.  La implementación de esto se encuentra en la clase `TComponent`.

Esto me permite *simplificar* la programación, manteniendo una cantidad pequeña de referencias. Por ejemplo, si vemos la implementación de la VCL, los controles visuales, generalmente son propiedad del formulario donde se encuentran y los formularios, a su vez, son propiedad del componente de aplicación, la variable `Application`. De esta manera, cuándo la aplicación termina, simplemente se libera la variable `Application`, lo que genera una cascada de liberación de todos los formularios y sus controles y con ello los recursos asociados a estos.

Un pequeño ejemplo en código, dónde como se ve, me preocupo de liberar únicamente al componente *padre* y eso me garantiza que se liberarán todos los componentes creados y sus recursos:

```
procedure TMiFormulario.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Padre: TComponent;
  Hijo: TComponent;  //esta variable está declarada por claridad del código, pero no es necesaria.
begin
  Padre := TComponentePadre.Create(nil);
  try
    Hijo := TComponenteHijo.Create(Padre);
    Hijo := TOtroComponente.Create(Padre);
    Hijo := TClientDataSet.Create(Padre);
    Hijo := TDataModule1.Create(Padre);
    RealizarAlgunTrabajo;
  finally
    Padre.Free; //acá se liberarán los 4 hijos como parte del proceso de liberación del padre.
  end;
end;
```

## `TInterfacedObject` y su contador de referencias

`TInterfacedObject` implementa la interfaz `IInterface` y, con ella, implementa un contador de referencias que, con la ayuda del compilador, permite la liberación automática de los objetos cuando las variables que hacen referencia a ellos salen de contexto.

La *magia* reside en 2 cosas.

La primera es implementar los métodos de `IInterface`, que son básicamente:

```
  IInterface = interface
    ['{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;
```

La segunda es realizada por el compilador, que automágicamente agrega las llamadas necesarias a `_AddRef` y `_Release`, cada vez que se realizan asignaciones a variables de tipo `IInterface` o sus derivados, así como cuando estas variables salen de contexto.

`_AddRef` es llamada cada vez que debe incrementarse el contador de referencias y `_Release` cada vez que debe decrementarse. La convención es que, si el contador de referencias llega a cero, debe liberarse el objeto.

Una implementación básica, aprovechando la herencia, puede ser declarar una clase que sirva como base para todos los componentes que quieras utilizar como interfaces, que herede directamente de `TComponent` o de la clase que te sirva como base (suponiendo que es una, o una clase por cada tipo específico de derivado de `TComponent` que te sirva como base, algo como:

```
type
  TMiComponenteBase = class(TComponent, IInterface); 
  private
    FContadorReferencias: Integer;
  public
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

  TMiComponente = class(TMiComponenteBase, IMiInterface)
  private
    procedure MiMetodoDeInterface(MisParametros: TMiTipo);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

function TMiComponenteBase.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TMiComponenteBase._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := AtomicIncrement(FContadorReferencias);
end;

function TMiComponenteBase._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := AtomicDecrement(FContadorReferencias);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;
```

Luego, puedes utilizar esta interface con la confianza que se liberará automáticamente, pues el compilador realiza el *trabajo sucio*.  Este código:

```
procedure TMiFormulario.MiMetodo;
var
  mInt: IMiInterface;
begin
  mInt := TMiComponente.Create(nil);
  mInt.MiMetodoDeInterface(123);
  //no es necesario liberar la variable mInt, ocurre automáticamente
end;
```

Es transformado, tras bambalinas, en algo como esto:

```
procedure TMiFormulario.MiMetodo;
var
  mInt: IMiInterface;
begin
  mInt := TMiComponente.Create(nil);
  try
    mInt._AddRef;
    mInt.MiMetodoDeInterface(123);
  finally
    mInt._Release;
  end;
  //no es necesario liberar la variable mInt, ocurre automáticamente
end;
```

Hay casos donde debes tener en cuenta que la llamada a `_Release` se realizará como parte del `end` final de la rutina (cuando la variable sale de contexto). El compilador se encarga de agregar las llamadas necesarias siempre que se realizan asignaciones y se pasan interfaces como parámetros, el mecanismo es muy robusto y si sigues las recomendaciones funcionará bien.

## Evita los conflictos entre ambos modelos

Una de las razones por las que me he tomado el tiempo de escribir una respuesta con tanto detalle es porque debes evitar provocar conflictos entre los modelos de gestión de memoria.

Una forma de evitar los conflictos es referenciar a un objeto de estos siempre a través de sus interfaces (nunca asignarlo a una variable de tipo objeto, solo interfaces).

Parte de esto es no asignar ningún propietario al llamar al constructor (los constructores de los componentes, por regla general, siempre esperan su propietario como único o como primer parámetro del constructor. Si ese es el caso, pasale `nil` como valor a dicho parámetro).  Si pasas otro componente a este parámetro, este componente almacenará una referencia de tipo objeto al que estás creando, rompiendo la regla.

De esta manera evitarás violaciones de acceso u otros problemas que pueden derivarse de mezclar los modelos.